# macvtap on vmware's VM

Tags: vmware, tap

Does macvtap bridging between VMWARE's VMs?

My application works over VMWARE VM and should handle traffic from the net.
I'm trying to use macvtap for that purpose:

ip link set dev eth1_index promisc on allmulticast on up
ip link add link eth1_index name macvtap1 type macvtap
ip link set dev macvtap1 promisc on allmulticast on up

Then, from the application i open /dev/tapX, set (via TUNSETIFF) it as (IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI) and try doing some traffic.

If i use eth1's mac to send/receive traffic to another VM on the same host, i see that TX packets are received well, and responses (destined to eth1's mac), are forwarded to eth1 but not to macvtap1 (so the application cannot read them).

If i use macvtap1's mac to send/receive traffic - i see (when capturing the other VM) that TX packets, with the macvtap's mac as source mac - are not delivered to it (i do see these packets when i capture the 'local' VM's eth1).

Also, if i just try (without my application) to define an IP over the macvtap interface and ping it from the other VM - i see that the ARP requests reaches eth1 but not macvtap1.

My questions are:
- Should macvtap work over VMWARE VMs?
- If yes, what did i do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it.

macvtap devices uses it's own mac for rx/tx.
So, for vmware in order for the vswitch to deliver the packet up to the VM,
i changed the port group's security setting, setting promiscous mode on. 
It worked.